# Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '‌'. insert statement SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2016

Hi i am getting this error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 5 Incorrect syntax near '‌' and i dont know from where is the problem. That is the code and also i attached a screenshot.

```
    USE CobornSalesDB;
GO
INSERT INTO SalesActivity
VALUES ('AC00001','05-12-2016','AG16170','C000001',
'P0001','S00002'‌​,1,200000.00,NULL,‌1.2220,20,100000.00,
'12-25-2016','12-30-2016','12-31-2016','A000001','PR00001'); 
GO                                                                                                                                      

                                                                                                                   ![SCREENSHOT][1]
```

Comment: (1) List the columns for an insert.  (2) Use ISO standard date formats (either `'2016-12-31'` or `'20161231'`.

Comment: I think this is actually a useful question because of the hidden characters inb the string. I've seen this before

Answer (score 2):

You have a hidden character

If I convert to ANSI in NotePad++

```
INSERT INTO
    SalesActivity
VALUES
    (
'AC00001',
'05-12-2016',
'AG16170',
'C000001',
'P0001',
'S00002'â€Œâ€‹, --this bad boy
1   ,
200000.00,
NULL,
1.2220,
20  ,
100000.00,
'12-25-2016',
'12-30-2016',
'12-31-2016',
'A000001',
'PR00001');
GO
```

Comment: Hi is not that  delete it and is showing the same error .:(

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev Works for me when I try it. There are 2 characters, unicode 8204 and 8203

Comment: now is giving me another error Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Line 3
Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.  USE CobornSalesDB;
GO
INSERT INTO SalesActivity
VALUES ('AC00001','05-12-2016','AG16170','C000001',
'P0001','S00002','1',200000.00,NULL,1.2220,100000.00,
'25-12-2016','30-12-2016','31-12-2016','A000001','PR00001'); 
GO

Comment: @GeorgiGeorgiev: then that error is obvious: you have too many or too few values.

Comment: there is another one further down by the 1.2220